# using comments_template() in custom single-portfolio.php

Tags: comments, comments-template

I am wanting my users to be able to post comments on my portfolio page.

Ive created a portfolio page using custom posts.

On my blog i am using the comments_template(); and then on the comments.php i have the code.

On the blog side it works 100%

But when I add the comments_template(); on the portfolio single page it does nothing.

I get no errors or anything.

How do people implement comments within the portfolio pages?

Can you not use the same comment.php file for all comments, b

Thanks

Comment: this may help you http://ryanflorence.com/getting-comments-to-display-on-home-page-of-a-wordpress-site/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When registering a custom post type you need to enable comments. In the arguments defining the CPT, you need to include something like this:

`'supports' => array( 'title', 'editor', 'author', 'thumbnail', 'excerpt', 'comments' )`

The example on the Codex is shows where this option needs to go, this page also shows a list of other options you may or may not want to include: http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_post_type#Example

Comment: thanks for that, I totally forgot about accepting it within the custom post supports.